# WebStorm - remove console.log before every commit

Tags: webstorm

How can I configure WebStorm IDE to automatically check and clean the code from all `console.log` on every commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option for this in the IDE, but you can use the packages available on the web and either include them in your build process or run as a pre-commit hook. See [babel-plugin-transform-remove-console](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console/), [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin)